# Delete words from text file if they exist in another textfile

Tags: python

I have created one txt.file, consisting of five other text files (all text.txt). I also have a text file with words on each line (remove words.txt). I would like to remove the words from removewords.txt from alltext.txt, without creating a new textfile and without writing the words from removewords.txt manually.

I have thought about using sets, but is a but confused how to approach this?

My mergin of files looks like this:

```
files=["file1.txt", "file2.txt"...."file5.txt"]
with open("compare_out.txt", "w") as fout:

for file in files:
    with open (file) as complete_file:
        for line in complete_file:
            fout.write(line)
```

Any suggestions? Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

1. read all words from "removewords.txt" into a list called `remove_words`
2. read all words from "alltext.txt" into a list called `all_words`
3. open the file "alltext.txt" in write mode (`"w"`) and write content to it as follows:

   - for each word in `all_words`, check if that word is in the list `remove_words`. If it is not, write it to "alltext.txt"

Are these steps detailed enough so that you can solve your problem?

If not, comment below on what you are having problems with.

Comment: Thank you for a great answer! But when I do this, I will manipulate the text more than necessary. Is there any way to only remove the words from removewords.txt and replace them with a space?

Comment: A (text) file is basically just a sequence of characters on your disk. This sequence needs to be continuous, there may not be "holes" in it. If you want to delete some words in the middle of the file, you would have to "move" all following words to fill the gap. The easiest option is to just write the whole file again (as I've shown above).

Comment: Is performance really a problem for your program? How large are your text files?

Answer (score 0):

If it is not a problem you can load all the words to remove in to a set using `split`, then check each word before you write it to the output file.
Split separates a string in to list elements based on a delimiting character - in the case of words we can use a space character `" "` to separate each word from other words.

```
rm_word_file = open('removewords.txt', 'r')
remove_words = set(rm_word_file.read().split(" "))
rm_word_file.close()
files=["file1.txt", "file2.txt"...."file5.txt"]

with open("compare_out.txt", "w") as fout:

    for file in files:
        with open (file) as complete_file:
            for line in complete_file:
                for word in line.split(" "):
                    if(word not in remove_words):
                        fout.write(line)
```

Something else to think about is, if there is punctuation in your text body, how you will handle that?

You can just remove all punctuation, but then its and it's would be treated as the same word, which may not be the intended behaviour.

Comment: There's an indentation error and you should close "removewords.txt".

Comment: This is not working for me. The text repeats itself several times :(

Comment: Can you describe the error/issue you are having in more depth?

Comment: Each text piece - separated by a newline - is printed five times in the output file

Comment: That is probably because there are 5 files no? I am confused what you actually want from your question -> These 5 text files you want to combine them how? Because currently we are just reading them one at a time.